# typescript - Object-property should be integer but is string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, types

I need to iterate throug a object `nodeIDs` and find the key-indexes of specific values..

```
 private getNodeIndexByID(nodeIDs, id) {
   for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(nodeIDs)) {
     if (id === value) {
       return key;
     }
   }
 }
```

the returned key is numeric
.. now I build a new object, where the key-indexes are saved

```
const index_source = this.getNodeIndexByID(nodeIDs, obj.source);
const index_target = this.getNodeIndexByID(nodeIDs, obj.target);

let my_obj = Object.create({}, { source: { value: index_source }, target: { value: index_target } });
out.push(my_obj);
```

now the values of `out.source` and `out.target` are typeOf STRING.. why? .. i mean, the array-index is numeric.. 
what am I missing? .. I need them to be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Keys of JavaScript objects are *always* (**always**!) strings, even if they were written to using numeric keys.

In other words,

```
x[0] = 1
```

is *exactly* the same as

```
x["0"] = 1
```

If you're numerating the key/value pairs of an object, you'll see string keys, because keys of JavaScript objects are always strings.

Comment: That was new to me, I'd have expected `x[0]` to only work on array objects.

Comment: Nit: [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) iterator will cause something like `for (const [key, value] of ['foo', 'bar'].entries())` to have `typeof key === 'number'`. Wouldn't that technically be a JavaScript object with numeric keys since `[] instanceof Object`?

Comment: The keys are still strings. `entries` converting them to a number on your behalf doesn't change that.

Comment: that is strange.. because i need to pass my object to a 3rd-party script, that has this code in it `if (typeof edge.source == "number") {..`